# Moving login/passwords firefox file

Tags: firefox, passwords

Where does firefox (3.5.1 if that matters) saves passwords ?

I need to move (only the) passwords from one firefox to a new one, but I don't wish to move the entire profile directory; to put it short, it has something to do with other options which I explicitly don't want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you can use the Weave extension to synch your passwords with another computer, but I've not had the best of luck with it lately...

If memory serves, it should be around C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\some­ thing.default\signons.txt

You may also need key3.db form that directory.

Oh, and you'll have to show hidden files/folders.

Answer (score 2):

Download and [Password Exporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2848) extension, you can them export it from your old profile as XML/CSV (optionally encrypted); and having installed it on your new profile, you can them import the file. Works from Firefox 2 - 3.6a1pre.

Answer (score 1):

I use [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) to preserve my favorites, history, etc from one Firefox install to another. The nice thing about MozBackup is that you can select what you would like to backup and restore to a new Firefox profile:

[image: MozBackup components selection during a backup.]